# Regex unable to identify int

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to match this url form `https://sub.example.com/dir/test-123456-23/programs`
The format of the URL is `https://sub.example.com/dir/test-<INTEGER>-<INTERGER>/programs`

I can't seem to get the regex to match the pattern

```
<?php

$pattern = '$https://sub.example.com/dir/test-+d-+d/programs$';

if (preg_match($pattern, "https://sub.example.com/dir/test-123456-23/programs")) {
    echo("This string is a valid url");
} else {
    echo("Not a valid url");
}
```

Valid Examples:

```
https://sub.example.com/dir/test-12-24323/programs
https://sub.example.com/dir/test-12-4/programs
https://sub.example.com/dir/test-123456-4293/programs
https://sub.example.com/dir/test-84341-1383/programs
https://sub.example.com/dir/test-210573089-2931/programs
https://sub.example.com/dir/test-210573089-1/programs
```

Invalid Examples:

```
https://sub.example.com/dir/test-1234a56-23/programs
https://sub.example.com/dir/test-12d3456-23s/programs
https://sub.example.com/dir/test-123456-23s/programs
https://sub.example.com/dir/test-123456-23/programs45d
https://sub.example.com/dir/book-123456-23/programs
https://sub.example.com/dir/test-12-24323/programs/more
```

Comment: Try: `$pattern = '~^https://sub\.example\.com/dir/test-\d+-\d+/programs$~';`

Comment: @anubhava Is there a pattern I can use to extract the 2 integers like this `<INTEGER>-<INTERGER>`

Comment: Use capture groups `(\d+-\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing new compared to anubhava comment, I only used the `\Q...\E` (QuotE) feature to avoid to escape special characters like the dot in literal parts, the `\A...\z` anchors in place of `^...$` (that allows a trailing newline) and the x modifier to ignore spaces in the pattern (to make it more readable):

```
$pattern = '~\A \Qhttps://sub.example.com/dir/test-\E (\d+-\d+) /programs \z~x';
```